# How to remove rows from a CSV with no data using AWK

Tags: bash, csv, awk, data-filtering

I am working with a large csv in a linux shell that I narrowed down to 3 columns:

Species name, Latitude, and Longitude.

```
awk -F "\t" '{print $10,","$22,",",$23}' occurance.csv > three_col.csv
```

The file ends up looking like this:

```
      species         | Lat     | Long   |
----------------------|---------|---------
Leucoraja erinacea    | 41.0748 | 72.9461|
Brevoortia tyrannus   | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
Paralichthys dentatus |         | 73.2354|
Paralichthys dentatus |         |        |
Leucoraja erinacea    | 41.0748 |        |
Brevoortia tyrannus   |         |        |
Brevoortia tyrannus   |         |        |
Paralichthys dentatus | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
Brevoortia tyrannus   | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
```

However this is what I want it to Look: Notice all species with no lat or long data have been removed

```
      species         | Lat     | Long   |
----------------------|---------|---------
Leucoraja erinacea    | 41.0748 | 72.9461|
Brevoortia tyrannus   | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
Paralichthys dentatus | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
Brevoortia tyrannus   | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
```

I've been trying to remove rows that are lacking either Lat or Long data. Using a line like this:

```
awk -F "\t" BEGIN '{print $1,$2,$3}' END '{$2!=" " && $3!= " " }' three_col.csv > del_blanks.csv
```

but it results in this error even with small changes that I make trying to solve the problem

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near end of line
```

**How can I get rid of these rows with missing data, is this something I need a "for" loop for?**

Comment: I think `awk -F "\t" '$2!=" " && $3!= " " {print $1,$2,$3}' file` should work

Comment: Based on what is shown, it seems unlikely that the empty fields contain a single space, which is what you are trying to match.

Comment: you mention the file was created via an `awk` script that uses a comma as a field delimiter but your sample data shows a pipe delimiter, while your follow-on `awk` code mentions a tab delimiter; you mention you want to remove rows with a missing value but the sample you've provided does not appear to have any rows with missing values; please update the question with an actual example from your file, making sure to demonstrate rows with and without missing fields; also update the question to show the expected output (corresponding to the sample input)

Comment: inside the quotes I have tried space, no space, and comma. it all results in the same error...
I just tried awk -F "\t" '$2!=" " && $3!= " " {print $1,$2,$3}' input.csv >output.csv 
no erro, but the file remained unchanged

Comment: I will update the question, but the -F "," does not work with this file. I was only able to get it to run using "\t". I also tried $2!="\t" in the code with no luck

Comment: your 2nd `awk` script is just completely wrong ... the `BEGIN` and `END` go inside the single quotes ... and you should only have a single set of single quotes; row-by-row processing goes between any `BEGIN` and `END` blocks (but `BEGIN/END` don't appear to have any use for this problem); *'but the -F "," does not work'* does not tell us anything useful (error? wrong answer?) and without seeing the actual data we have no idea why the `-F ","` *does not work*

Comment: your updated sample still does not make sense ... comma delimiter in output from first `awk` script ... data shows pipe delimiter ... your 2nd `awk` script is looking for a tab delimiter; assuming the first 10 lines of the file contain some missing fields ... please update the question with the output from the following: `cat -A three_col.csv | head` ... just cut-n-paste the output into the question ... do not reformat, do not add anything ... this should show us exactly what's in your file (including delimiters)

Comment: @Common_Codin: Is your csv file pipe delimited as shown?

Comment: I will try my best to update the question according to your comments. Yes I am very new to awk so "its completely wrong" is not a helpful comment. If I knew how to do it I would not be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know what your occurance.csv file looks like, this is a shot in the dark:

```
awk -F "\t" '$22 && $23 {print $10,","$22,",",$23}' occurance.csv > three_col.csv
```

The expression `$22 && $23` says: Both field 22 and field 23 must not be blank. It is a condition to filter out those lines which don't qualify. It is a shorthand for `$22 != "" && $3 != ""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    awk -F "|" '
        {
        if (substr($1,1,1) == "-"){  
          e = ""
        }else{
          e=FS
        }
        gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2)
        gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $3)
        
        if(length($2) !=0 && length($3) !=0){
          printf "%s%s%-9s%s%-8s%s\n", $1, FS, $2, FS, $3, e
        }
}' file.txt

      species         | Lat     | Long   |
----------------------|---------|---------
Leucoraja erinacea    | 41.0748 | 72.9461|
Brevoortia tyrannus   | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
Paralichthys dentatus | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
Brevoortia tyrannus   | 39.0748 | 70.9461|
```

Answer (score -1):

perhaps something like this ?

```
 mawk '($!NF=$10","$22","$23)!~",,$"' FS='\t' OFS=','
```

You already know only fields `10/22/23` needs to be printed, so you can first overwrite `$0` with those just 3 columns, already-split by `OFS`

afterwards simply use a quick regex check, since 2 consecutive `OFS` at the tail is the sign `$22` and `$23` are empty - saving the print statement and pattern-action blocks.